# How to prevent laptop resolution changing when connecting to a 4k TV (Monteray 12.2.1)

Tags: display, resolution

I read the older post from 6 years stating to look for arrangements on display settings, but that setting has gone. How do we prevent the laptop from changing resolution when connecting to another monitor / 4k TV?

Comment: Which older post are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

In System Preferences > Displays, you need to set the external monitor for "Extend Desktop" instead of "Mirroring". That way the internal monitor can have one resolution, and the external monitor a different resolution.